# Force apache-toree scala kernel to add dependency from local repo

Tags: apache-spark, apache-toree

In apache-toree scala kernel, `%AddDeps` magics can be used to load the dependencies.  How can I force it to use the local repo instead of mavenCentral?

Answer (score 0):

```
%AddDeps org.example my-project 5.0 --repository file:/users/my-home/.m2/repository --transitive
```